# disable a button click based on recursive component rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, recursion

Refer [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-create-multilevel-dropdown-menu-react/) for implementing multi-level menu items.

I have a menuItem component:

```
export default function MenuItems({ items, depthLevel }: { items: MenuItemsI, depthLevel: number }): ReturnType<FC> {
    const [
        dropdown,
        setDropdown
    ] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const ref = useRef<HTMLLIElement>();

    useEffect(() => {
        const handler = (event: MouseEvent) => {
            if (
                dropdown &&
            ref.current &&
            !ref.current.contains(event.target as Node)
            ) {
                setDropdown(false);
            }
        };
        document.addEventListener('mousedown', handler);
        document.addEventListener('touchstart', handler);
        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener('mousedown', handler);
            document.removeEventListener('touchstart', handler);
        };
    }, [dropdown]);

    function onMouseEnter() {
        if (depthLevel > 0) {
            setDropdown(true);
        }
    }

    function onMouseLeave() {
        if (depthLevel > 0) {
            setDropdown(false);
        }
    }

    function closeDropdown() {
        setDropdown(!dropdown);
    }

    return (
        <li
            className={`${styles["menu-items"]} ${depthLevel === 0 ? styles.main : styles.sub}`}
            ref={ref}
            onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter}
            onMouseLeave={onMouseLeave}
            onClick={closeDropdown}
        >
            {items.submenu ? (
                <>
                    <div
                        aria-haspopup="menu"
                        aria-expanded={dropdown ? 'true' : 'false'}
                        // onClick={() => setDropdown((prev) => !prev)}
                        className={`${styles["menu-item"]}`}
                    >
                        <span>{items.title}</span>
                        <span
                            className={`${styles.arrow}`}
                        >
                            {((depthLevel === 0 && !dropdown) || depthLevel > 0) ? (
                                <BiCaretRight size="20px" />
                            ) : (
                                <BiCaretDown size="20px" />
                            )}
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <Dropdown
                        depthLevel={depthLevel}
                        submenus={items.submenu}
                        dropdown={dropdown}
                    />
                </>
            ) : (
                <Link className={`${styles["menu-item"]}`} to="/">{items.title}</Link>
            )}
        </li>
    );
}
```

And a Dropdown component:

```
export default function Dropdown({ submenus, dropdown, depthLevel }: any): ReturnType<FC> {
    const [localDepthLevel, setLocalDepthLevel] = useState(depthLevel + 1);

    useEffect(() => {
        setLocalDepthLevel(depthLevel + 1);
    }, [depthLevel]);

    // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
    depthLevel += 1;
    return (
        <ul
            className={`${styles.dropdown} ${depthLevel > 1 ? `${styles["dropdown-submenu"]}` : ``} ${
                dropdown ? `${styles.show}` : ''
            }`}
        >
            {submenus.map((submenu: any, index: number) => (
                <MenuItems
                    items={submenu}
                    key={index}
                    depthLevel={localDepthLevel}
                />
            ))}
        </ul>
    );
}
```

where the MenuItems is defined as:

```
export interface MenuItemsI {
    title: string,
    submenu?: Array<MenuItemsI>
}


export const menuItems: MenuItemsI[] = [
    {
        title: "Rules",
        submenu: [
            {
                title: "menu 1",
                submenu: [
                    {
                        title: "submenu 1",
                        submenu: [
                            {
                                title: "subsubmenu 1"
                            },
                            {
                                title: "subsubmenu 2"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        title: "submenu 2",
                        submenu: [
                            {
                                title: "subsubmenu 3"
                            },
                            {
                                title: "subsubmenu 4"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                title: "menu 2",
                submenu: [
                    {
                        title: "submenu 3"
                    },
                    {
                        title: "submenu 4"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                title: "menu 3"
            }

        ]
    }
];
```

I am trying to implement the `function closeDropdown()` such that if we are at a leaf menuItem (i.e., it has not submenus) then we can click on it. And if the menuItem has submenus then it is not clickable but can hover and show its submenus (not the hover and show submenus is working fine).

I have tried multiple ways of logic however it seems due to the recursive nature of the rendering of components, the call stack will eventually be at every logical condition, thus it will always close on a click no matter how the implementation is?

Is this the case? Any help is appreciated thanks!

Things I have tried:

```
if (depthLevel === 0) {
    setDropdown(!dropdown); // Toggle the dropdown for the main button
  } else if (depthLevel === 1 && items.submenu) {
    // Prevent closing if submenu has submenus
    setDropdown(true);
  } else if (!items.submenu) {
    setDropdown(false); // Close the dropdown for leaf menu items
  }
```

or

```
if (depthLevel === 0) {
    setDropdown(!dropdown); // Toggle the dropdown for the main button
  } else if (!items.submenu) {
    setDropdown(false); // Close the dropdown for leaf menu items
  }
```

or

```
if (depthLevel === 0 || !items.submenu) {
    setDropdown(false);
  } else {
    setDropdown(true);
  }
```

or

```
if (depthLevel === 0 || !items.submenu) {
    setDropdown(false);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Think it may be simpler to handle the states locally and look at the object data to resolve any data driven behaviours such as whether or not the item is clickable.

The type is already good and looking at submenu value you know if its clickable and if hover should display anything.

I don't know keeping track of depth level on each component is useful, think trying to pass stateful data between recursions is complicated and maybe there are better ways.

If you have a component like this, that renders its title and submenus if hovered

```
export interface ItemData {
  title: string;
  submenu?: Array<ItemData>;
}

const Menu = (props: { readonly items: readonly ItemData[] }) => {
  const [hovered, setHovered] = useState<string | null>(null);
  return (
    <div>
      {props.items.map((data) => (
        <li
          onMouseOver={() => setHovered(data.title)}
          onMouseLeave={() => setHovered(null)}
        >
          {data.title}
          {data.submenu && data.title === hovered && (
            <Menu items={data.submenu} />
          )}
        </li>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Then a simple function like this to test against one item's data

```
const isLeaf = (item: ItemData) => !item.submenu;
```

You can have then have onClick on the div

```
onClick={() => {
  if (isLeaf(data)) {
    alert("click");
  }
}}
```

Or you can render a button instead for leaves or whatever works for your project.

Here's an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-zv5dzg?file=/src/App.tsx)

If you want to get additional information about the data such as depth level you can do that again on the data, outside of the component even, without needing to pass data between recursive components.

The kind of data structure is similar to a tree so you can do a lot of what you would do on trees on it, it's good to have an id / key, here can use title if its unique but you can add id eventually.

For example, something like this might work

```
const getKey=(item:ItemData)=>item.title;


const getDepth = (root:ItemData, item:ItemData)=>{

  const depth = (at:ItemData, current=-1):number=>{
    if(getKey(item)===getKey(at)){
      return current;
    }
    if(at.submenu===undefined) return 0;
    return at.submenu.reduce((pre,curr)=>pre+depth(curr, current+1),0)
  }

  return depth(root)
}
```

Here you need a reference to the data itself so you have context within which to place item for which the depth you're looking for. If this is static you can just reference a variable in the file outside the components, if it's fetched you can pass it to the components, even if they are recursively rendered the data is not changing so there are no complications about keeping track and stuff..

Updated [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-54hk7r?file=/src/App.tsx) to show how can use.

Comment: I like your solution a lot, but I have different styling based on the `depthLevel = 0` vs `depthLevel > 0` and I am not sure how to detect that the way you have it set up unless I do use a `depthLevel` variable at first to pass in ? The styling is the same as major navigations, where first level is a row and the submenu items are displayed as columns

Comment: yea nice, I would still do it on the data itself. I'll add some example

Comment: you might want to check the depth function just mocked it up seems to work but haven't really tested much. But the idea is more important, to basically rely as much as possible on the data directly and less logic in components.