# How to test detect click outside a React component with Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs

Refer [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-create-multilevel-dropdown-menu-react/) for context on multilevel menu rendering.

I am trying to test the detection of a click outside the component. All the examples I have seen so far are different than the implementation that I have and thus do not work.

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76694471/disable-a-button-click-based-on-recursive-component-rendering/76699484?noredirect=1#comment135237640_76699484) for the full components I have written so far.

The test I have tried so far is:

```
it("detect click outside", () => {

    const setStateMock = jest.fn();
    const useStateMock: any = (useState: any) => [useState, setStateMock];
    jest.spyOn(React, 'useState').mockImplementation(useStateMock);

    render(<BrowserRouter >
        <MenuItems items={submenusMock} depthLevel={0}/>
    </BrowserRouter>);

    const button = screen.getByTestId("button");

    expect(button).toBeInTheDocument();
    fireEvent.click(button);

    fireEvent.click(document);

    expect(setStateMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Where I click a button to have the `useEffect` hook add event listener to the document and then click outside the component. But it does not seem to work.

Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-kvws8f?file=/src/App.tsx) working. The tests are in the `__tests__` folder where the codesandbox is not sufficient enough with a free tier to run the test. So need to run test on own machine.

Comment: Please give a [mre].

Comment: The call to render returns a container. Click on that container

Comment: I do `const { container } = render(...)` then click a button to cause useEffect to fire off then I do `fireEvent.click(container)` but it does not work for me

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't ever mock `useState` or its returns. Instead, you should check to see that your component behaves as expected. Let's imagine that you have a modal that opens on click of a button and closes on click of the background. Your tests could be revised to look like this:

```
describe('opening and closing modal', () => {
    test('should open modal when button is clicked', () => {
       // better to select on what the user is looking for
       const btn = screen.getByText('Open modal');
       // don't need to check if it is in the document, bc fireEvent will error if it is not
       fireEvent.click(btn);
       expect(screen.getByTestId('my-modal')).toBeVisible();
    });
    test('should close modal when background clicked', () => {
       const btn = screen.getByText('Open modal');
       fireEvent.click(btn);

       fireEvent.click(screen);
       expect(screen.getByTestId('my-modal')).not.toBeVisible();
    });
});
```

HTH

Comment: This does not help answer my original question because another component that I do no care about changes based on that state so I need to track changes on the state. And I do not think `shouldn't ever mock useState` is true for all situations.

Comment: @OwenMurphy you’re right that it isn’t directly relevant to your original question. You’re wrong if you think it’s ok to mock useState under any circumstance

Comment: @AdamJenkins, Oh interesting, can you provide docs for where I can read about this to educate myself on the justification for why NOT to mock useState? It seems a lot of the resources online have been to mock useState.

Comment: There’s a lot of wrong resources online. You’re testing implementation details by mocking  useState - test the behaviour of the component, not its implementation details.

Comment: My point is you should be checking to see that the actual behavior of the component is correct. It doesn't matter even a little if the state contains a specific value if that doesn't drive correct behavior. Write your tests so they look and see if the correct thing happened as a result of the click.

Comment: If I were going to mock something you shouldn't mock in this scenario, I'd mock addEventListener to capture the callback that was added and removeEventListener to ensure the listener was removed on unmount, because it's actually important not to have memory leaks.

Comment: Thank you for that. However, could have just commented that. this answer does not help answer my question in my case as indicated in the comments above.

Comment: You are saying I should or I should not mock the `addEventListener` ? for the `document.addEventListener()` call ?

Comment: It actually does. It's clear you're just starting out with TDD and don't really understand the basic principles behind it. I've been doing TDD for over 10 years, so I can give you insight that will help you if you'll listen.

Comment: I wouldn't. But if I were the type of person to disregard that type of advice, I would think it's way more important to check that my component isn't going to cause a memory leak vs. seeing what is happening in its private internal variables.

Comment: This is correct, I am still in the process of learning best practices for react unit/integration testing using jest as well as TDD as you say.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254537/discussion-between-amy-blankenship-and-owen-murphy).

Comment: this answer looks good. This should cover click outside works. Generally testing UI you want to test as closely as possible to the how the user interacts. If you want to test specific logic for one or more functions used in the actual click outside logic you can do that as well and pass different input asserting outputs.

Comment: Also sometimes you can't get out of mocking stuff, and even sometime it is useful. But generally would avoid mocking as much as possible.

Comment: @Max it does not seem to work for my case as Typescript throws the error: `Argument of type 'Screen<typeof import("/Users/owenmurphy/Desktop/opus/opus-app/node_modules/@testing-library/dom/types/queries")>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Element | Node | Document | Window'.` when trying to perform `fireEvent.click(screen);`

Comment: This was just example/pseudocode. Use the debug method in RTL to see what parent elements you can grab to click.